# How to populate a MySQL database with Excel spreadsheets?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I've written a basic SQL script to create a database and I was wondering if it would be possible to populate the tables from Excel documents? The tables I have created are not currently identical to the Excel tables so would it also be possible to specify which rows to populate from? Or should I create a new Excel document that is identical in structure to the tables in my database?

An example table I have created would be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rota (
date DATE NOT NULL ,
cleaner1 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
cleaner2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (date) );
```

What would I need to add to this script to populate this table from an Excel document?

Comment: usually whatever IDE you are using to handle sql queries has the option to import csv files.. maybe you should look into that.

Comment: you must have the same order in excel file and load data like this `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5...) `

Comment: Looking into csv suggestion now, cheers for the advice.

Comment: if you really are forced to it...you can use excel to mass create a series of insert statements. Add a column to the sheet that says insert into table values( then your first value, add a column with comma, and so on.  Copy the rows to the end of the data set and you'll have a series of single line inserts. It's ugly with pretty much every other solution you can find being better, but it will work...especially on smaller data sets.

Comment: Thanks for adding your own answer here. The best way to do that is to self-answer, as below, and tick it to indicate the question is answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

*Posted on behalf of the OP*.

Cheers for the advice to look into CSV files. If anyone looking at this in the future wants to use CSV files as well my script looked like this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE hotel.rota;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Lewis\\Desktop\\rota.csv'
INTO TABLE hotel.rota FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (date,cleaner1,cleaner2);
```